# Using sklearn Pipelines with mlxtend SequentialFeatureSelector gives an error

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, mlxtend

I am trying to remove some unimportant features for one of my personal projects. Certain but not all features need scaling. I decided to do select the features using `SequentialFeatureSelector` from `mlxtend` with cross validation. My understanding is that I need to use `Pipeline` in order to scale folds properly but it is giving me an error.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
from mlxtend.feature_selection import SequentialFeatureSelector as SFS
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.utils import compute_sample_weight
import random

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': random.sample(range(1, 1000), 100),
    'b': random.sample(range(1, 1000), 100),
    'c': random.sample(range(1, 1000), 100),
    'd': random.sample(range(1, 1000), 100),
    'e': random.sample(range(1, 1000), 100),
    })

X_train = data.drop(columns=['a'], axis=1)
y_train = data['a']

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('scaler', StandardScaler(), ['b', 'd'])], 
                                 remainder='passthrough')
pipeline = Pipeline([('preprocessor', preprocessor), 
                     ('estimator', Ridge())])
weights = compute_sample_weight(class_weight='balanced', y=y_train)

sfs = SFS(pipeline, 
          k_features='best', 
          forward=False, 
          floating=True, 
          verbose=2, 
          scoring='neg_root_mean_squared_error', 
          cv=5)
sfs = sfs.fit(X_train, y_train, estimator__sample_weight=weights)
```

The error is:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py:372: FitFailedWarning: 
5 fits failed out of a total of 5.
The score on these train-test partitions for these parameters will be set to nan.
If these failures are not expected, you can try to debug them by setting error_score='raise'.

Below are more details about the failures:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
5 fits failed with the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py", line 409, in _get_column_indices
    all_columns = X.columns
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 680, in _fit_and_score
    estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 390, in fit
    Xt = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params_steps)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 355, in _fit
    **fit_params_steps[name],
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/joblib/memory.py", line 349, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 893, in _fit_transform_one
    res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py", line 672, in fit_transform
    self._validate_column_callables(X)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py", line 352, in _validate_column_callables
    transformer_to_input_indices[name] = _get_column_indices(X, columns)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py", line 412, in _get_column_indices
    "Specifying the columns using strings is only "
ValueError: Specifying the columns using strings is only supported for pandas DataFrames

  warnings.warn(some_fits_failed_message, FitFailedWarning)
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   2 out of   2 | elapsed:    0.0s finished
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/mlxtend/feature_selection/sequential_feature_selector.py:612: RuntimeWarning: Mean of empty slice
  all_avg_scores.append(np.nanmean(cv_scores))

[2022-04-09 06:26:03] Features: 1/1 -- score: nan

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-5-b7df58cec335> in <module>()
     33           scoring='neg_root_mean_squared_error',
     34           cv=5)
---> 35 sfs = sfs.fit(X_train, y_train, estimator__sample_weight=weights)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/mlxtend/feature_selection/sequential_feature_selector.py in fit(self, X, y, custom_feature_names, groups, **fit_params)
    566                     best_subset = k
    567             k_score = max_score
--> 568             k_idx = self.subsets_[best_subset]['feature_idx']
    569 
    570             if self.k_features == 'parsimonious':

KeyError: None
```

I know that it something to do with `ColumnTransformer` because it runs when remove this step. I've tried adding an extra step to convert to dataframe but it didn't help. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Please post the **full** error trace. Your posted trace reports problem at a line `all_columns = X.columns`, which is not to be seen in your code; there is more.

Comment: updated the error message. code is full.